# How do I select Edges?

Tags: mesh, nurbs-surface

I apologize in advance for asking such a beginners question, and I assume this will come down to my view/window being wrong.

I used Blender a few years back, and I am familiar with how shapes work and the interface it had years ago. Now back then, if I wanted to select vertices/edges/faces, I would click the appropriate icon next to the Object/Edit dropdown box, but as you can see, it is no longer there.

[image]

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html#selection-mode), pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> should produce the same effect, but it as well does not seem to change anything. I am able to select and move vertices, as this is the default behaviour but I cannot seem to be able to change to edge or face select.

I am using Blender v2.78c, and it looks quite different from when I downloaded it a few months ago, when those buttons were still where I was used to seeing them.

Comment: No-repro. Try looking a bit more to the right, just off the crop.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. [Here](http://puu.sh/xactO/d998053cd3.png) is my entire bottom toolbar.
EDIT: I appear to have been wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you're editing a mesh?

Comment: I just opened one of my old projects and the icons are there, but when I reopen my new project, the icons are no longer there. How can I tell if what I am editing is a mesh or not, and how can I change it if it is not? I started with the circle and have been expanding it out. [Current project](http://puu.sh/xacRd/a9e582218e.jpg), with no icons in toolbar.

Comment: Yep, that's not a mesh but a NURBS surface.

Comment: You're right. I deleted it and added the proper circle and I'll start over. Thank you for your help. If you post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it so you get the reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit Edges and Faces you need to be editing a mesh, and you will get the buttons as shown below:

[image]

Please note that these buttons will not be available for Curves, Nurbs, Text, Lamps, camera, Metaballs, Armatures, Lattices, Empties or any kind of object not consisiting of vertices, edges or faces.